# What do I do when I find a low-quality tag wiki and I'm not knowledgeable enough about its subject matter to improve it myself?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-wiki, faq-proposed

I think we should have a flag for moderator attention button for tag wikis.

**EDIT**

OK I get it that flags should not be used for such things, but We really need to address the fact that tag wikis get very less attention presently. We need to give them more attention. And I want to discuss the possible options for it in this post.

**EDIT**

After the discussion so far, Changing from feature-request to faq-proposed

Comment: I don't understand at all. What purpose would this serve, what should a moderator do about the Tag Wiki's low quality?

Comment: Do you possess enough rep to delete it?

Comment: Do you just want to ask someone to fill in a tag wiki? In other words, are you asking for a mechanism—like bounties—to draw attention to neglected tag wikis?

Comment: Yes. Bounties may be a solution, or maybe we should be allowed to post questions like: "The tag wiki for 'XYZ' Technology is poor, please post possible entries here" or something on those lines

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that flags were ever really intended to be used this way. You flag posts for moderator attention if you think that they need to be disposed of or are otherwise beyond saving. For the most part, these consist of spam as well as questions and comments posted as answers. You should *not* flag something because you think that it is technically inaccurate: that's what downvotes are for.

I agree that tag wikis are a bit more difficult to deal with because you cannot downvote them if you believe they are inaccurate or low quality. However, you *can* edit tag wikis (or at least make suggested edits) to improve them and correct any technical inaccuracies that you find.

If, however, you notice a number of empty tag wikis that could use some attention and *you aren't knowledgeable enough about the subject material to edit them yourself,* you could try asking the community here on Meta.SO to improve them. Be careful, though: you'll probably run into some backlash if you ask a new question on Meta for each and every tag wiki that you want improved. I would suggest finding and prioritizing a handful of tag wikis to include in your post here, if you are so inclined.

[msh210](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/161792/msh210) makes a good point that you should only ask the Meta Stack Overflow community for help improving tag wikis on Stack Overflow or Meta Stack Overflow. If you would like to ask for help improving tag wikis on other sites, ask their respective Meta communities.

Comment: ok i understand that but there should be some way of increasing the attention that tag wikis get right now

Comment: Re "asking the community here on Meta.SO": yes, if the tag wikis are on SO or meta.SO. If they're on, e.g., bicycles.SE, use meta.bicycles.SE. (Pinging @MozenRath too.)

Answer (score 3):

> What do I do when I think a tag wiki has low quality and I don't possess enough knowledge to improve its quality?

Nothing

Comment: I don't think doing nothing will help anybody.

Comment: In some cases, it does